# python-facebook-sdk remove like

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to make a like toggle button on my website which puts/removes likes on a facebook post using the [python-faecbook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/). But in the documentation  only a method to [put_like](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#put-like) is given.I'll be glad if anyone can figure out a way to delete the like.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that SDK doesn’t offer a dedicated method for this, then you’ll need to make the API request yourself. (If it doesn’t offer a way to do _that_ either … then you’ll have to write your own method, or do it “around” the SDK.)

Comment: Alright, thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove a like by making a DELETE request, such as: `DELETE /v2.3/{object-id}/likes HTTP/1.1 Host: graph.facebook.com`

A user access token with `publish_actions` permission can be used to remove existing likes by that user.